# Hide inventory message on product page based on available stock quantity

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a site which needs to display the available stock left for each product, which is fine. However some products are print on demand (i.e. infinite stock) so I have these loaded with 99999999 in stock. Obviously I don't want this stock level to show on the front end of the site as there isn't really any physical stock.

I've found the below snippet - can this be edited to say, for example, if the current stock is more than 1000 then hide the stock message?

```
function my_wc_hide_in_stock_message( $html, $text, $product ) {
    $availability = $product->get_availability();

    if ( isset( $availability['class'] ) && 'in-stock' === $availability['class'] ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_html', 'my_wc_hide_in_stock_message', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! You can check using the `get_stock_quantity()` method.

```
function my_wc_hide_in_stock_message( $html, $text, $product ) {
    $availability = $product->get_availability();
    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if ( isset( $availability['class'] ) && 'in-stock' === $availability['class'] && $stock_qty > 1000 ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_html', 'my_wc_hide_in_stock_message', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to change `'in-stock' === $availability['class'] || $stock_qty > 1000` to `'in-stock' === $availability['class'] && $stock_qty > 1000` otherwise it removed the message from all in-stock products not just those with more than 1000, now it works perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: @Lyall Oh yeah! You're right. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS.

```
.woocommerce .ribbons .ribbon.out-of-stock {
    display: none;
}
```